# Why am I getting the error "no find or load main class"

Tags: apache-kafka, scala-ide

I am getting the same error again and again. It does not show any code error, the object is in within the package.

[image: could not find or load main class com.mycom.sparkWscala.streaming]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find or load main class com.mycom.sparkWscala.streaming.kafkaWC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206628/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-mycom-sparkwscala-streaming-kafkawc)

Comment: Please read [this article](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [this related article](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) to understand why people might download this post.

Comment: I think this problem has more to do with running the code in question from the scala-ide rather than with Apache Kafka itself.

Answer (score 0):

The red x icon on your package and project indicates there is a compilation problem with some of the code, it seems to be in twitterdata.scala. While eclipse in general allows for partial compilation it may be that that it causes some problem for the scala-ide plugin. I suggest you try to fix or remove the offending code first. It is possible that the compilation does not produce the kafkaWC class, therefore when trying to run it, it reports the class not found error.

Hope that points you in the right direction.